# Svn hanging after typing one character when input is required?

Tags: svn, crash, windows-10, tortoisesvn, freeze

I'm using a new laptop with Windows 10 and Tortoise SVN 1.12.. I've tried 1.11 and 1.10 but all seem to have the same issue for me on this machine and i'm trying to work out what it could be and just wondering if anyone else has seen anything similar. Basically when ever you have to respond to a prompt form svn, such as for a password / username prompt or resolving conflict it takes one key press and then hangs.... so entering a password one * character gets put on screen then the cmd or powershell process i'm executing the svn command line on hangs. Tortoise GUI however works fine. The shell host becomes responsive again if you kill the svn.exe process in task manager so the problem seems to be in the svn.exe process.